# Is my answer to this question wrong?

Tags: proof-verification

Let $k$ be a real number and let
$f(x) := x^{2} + 2(k-2)x + k$.
Find the range of $k$ if $\alpha > \beta$ are such that
$f(x) = 0$
for $x = \alpha, \beta$ and if
$\beta < -1 < \alpha.$

The given answer is $k < 1.$ However, I suspect it is wrong. For, we have
$$\beta = -k+2 - \sqrt{(k-1)(k-4)} < -1 < -k+2 + \sqrt{(k-1)(k-4)} = \alpha,$$
and both inequalities lead to $k > 5.$

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @yashg: Ah, thanks very much. :)